# How to use other Jekyll themes on github pages than the officialy supported ones

Tags: github, jekyll

According to [Github](https://pages.github.com/themes/), the following is the list of jekyll themes it supports:

- Architect
- Cayman
- Dinky
- Hacker
- Leap day
- Merlot
- Midnight
- Minima Minimal
- Modernist
- Slate
- Tactile
- Time machine

If I want to use any theme apart from these, is there any way to go about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `theme` entry from your `_config.yml` file (so that you tell Jekyll you're not using a preexisting theme) and commit all the files and layouts that belong to the theme you want to use into the Git repository along with everything else you have (posts, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Found the way. To use another theme than the ones specified, do not commit the source jekyll files to the master branch.

Instead, run `jekyll build --destination dist` and then commit the contents of the `dist` directory to the master branch.